# Hi, i need to know if there is a way to "df.to_excel" function writes only in a specifics columns

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-excel

I'm trying to copy a Data Frame from one Excel(A) to other(B) but the "df.to_excel" funcion delete all the info from the second Excel (B) and I want to only paste the info from de Table A in the Table B without change anything from B

This is what I Have, but I don't know if is possible to do that with "df.to_excel":

```
data_1 = 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Raw Data.xlsx' 

with pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Final Data.xlsx',engine='openpyxl', 
    mode='a',if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer_1:

data_1.to_excel(writer_1,sheet_name='Arch_1',header=True,index=False,merge_cells=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  The pandas `df.to_excel` function replaces the entire file.  If you need to merge, you'll need to do that in your code.